# How to select points with datetime cordinates in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, matplotlib, floating-point

I am trying to implement [this lasso selection](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/lasso_demo.html), but I get:

```
  ...
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 1481, in add_collection
    self.update_datalim(collection.get_datalim(self.transData))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 185, in get_datalim
    offsets = np.asanyarray(offsets, np.float_)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 372, in asanyarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
  TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

This is probably because my data-points' x-coordinates are of type `datetime.datetime`.

I tried:

```
xdata = xdata.astype('datetime64[us]').astype('float')
```

This eliminates the TypeError, but then points never get selected, i.e `contains_points` always returns `False`s:

```
p = path.Path(verts)
ind = p.contains_points(self.xys)
```

How can I make the `collection` work with `datetime` `offsets`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your points aren't getting selected is that matplotlib's internal date representation isn't the same as numpy's.  (Numpy's datetime dtype is very new. Matplotlib currently needs to support numpy versions that don't have a datetime dtype, so matplotlib's internal date representation can't be dropped yet.)

The `xdata` that you're passing in gets converted using `matplotlib.dates.date2num`.  Just convert your `xys` data to the same representation and things should work. (I'll try to post a complete example in a bit...)